# Porque é que ao inserir 3 objetos só me aparece o último?

Tags: java

Preciso criar uma classe `carro`. O programa deve conter uma coleção de carros do tipo `ArrayList`. O seu programa deve permitir adicionar, eliminar e consultar carros ao do `ArrayList`.

Implementei dois programas um para `main` e outro para `carro.java`. Então a minha duvida é que eu consigo inserir e consultar dados dos carros, mas se eu inserir dados relativos a três automóveis mostra apenas o último, aponta para o último carro.

Classe `main.java`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Carro car = new Carro();
        int op;

        do {
            System.out.println("[1] Inserir");
            System.out.println("[2] Consultar");
            System.out.println("[3] Remover");
            System.out.println("[4] Sair");
            System.out.print("Opção desejada: ");
            op = input.nextInt();
            Object matricula;

            switch (op) {
            case 1:
                input.nextLine();                       /*Pretendo Inserir dados*/
                System.out.print("Matricula: ");
                car.setMatricula(input.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Marca: ");
                car.setMarca(input.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Modelo: ");
                car.setModelo(input.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Cor: ");
                car.setCor(input.nextLine());

                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Matricula: " + car.getMatricula());
                System.out.println("Marca: " + car.getMarca());
                System.out.println("Modelo: " + car.getModelo());
                System.out.println("Cor: " + car.getCor());
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("Matricula: ");
                car.setMatricula("");
                car.setMarca("");
                car.setModelo("");
                car.setCor("");
                break;
            }
        } while (op != 4);
    }

    public class Stand {

        private ArrayList<Carro> listaStand = new ArrayList<Carro>();

        public void insereCarro(Stand Carro)        //aqui pretendo inserir dados carro*/
        {
            listaStand.add(Carro);
        }

    public void consultaCarro()             //Aqui pretendo fazer consulta dos carros do stand */
        {
            for (Carro c: listaStand) 
            {
                System.out.println(listaStand.get(0));
            }
        }

     public String removeCarro(String Stand) {  //*aqui pretendo remover carro pela matricula
            for (Carro c : this.listaStand) {
                if (c.getMatricula().equals(Stand))
                    c.remove();
            }
    }}}
```

Classe `carro.java`

```
public class Carro
{
    String marca;
    String modelo;
    String matricula;
    String cor;
    private String Stand;

    public void Carro(String matricula, String marca, String modelo,  String cor)
    {
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.cor = cor;
    }
    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public String getCor() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setCor(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " matricula=" + matricula +",marca=" + marca + ", modelo=" + modelo +  ",cor=" + cor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Se ao invés disso: `for (Carro c: listaStand) 
            {
                System.out.println(listaStand.get(0));
            }` você fizer isso: `for (Carro c: listaStand) 
            {
                System.out.println(c);
            }`?

Comment: Porque é que estão a fechar esta pergunta?

Comment: @JorgeB. Também achei estranho. Estou votando para "Deixar aberta" na fila de análise.

Comment: Nota: nomes de classes devem começar com maiúsculas

Answer (score 3):

Comece por criar um *Stand*.

```
Stand stand = new Stand();
```

Sempre que é escolhida a opção 'Inserir' deve criar um novo carro, preecher os seus atributos e, no fim, adicioná-lo ao *Stand*.

```
case 1:
    carro = new carro();
    ...
    ....
    ....
    stand.insereCarro(carro);
    break;
```

**Nota:** O método `insereCarro()` da classe *Stand* deve receber um *Carro* e não um *Stand*

Na opção 'Consultar' chame o método `consultaCarro()` da classe *Stand*

```
case 2:
    stand.consultaCarro();
    break;
```

Passe os `System.out.println()` para dentro desse método:

```
public void consultaCarro() //Aqui pretendo fazer consulta dos carros do stand */
    {
        for (Carro c: listaStand) 
        {
            System.out.println("Matricula: " + c.getMatricula());
            System.out.println("Marca: " + c.getMarca());
            System.out.println("Modelo: " + c.getModelo());
            System.out.println("Cor: " + c.getCor());
        }
    }
```

Na opção 'Remover' terá de perguntar ao usuário qual a matricula do carro que quer remover e chamar o método `removeCarro()`.

```
case 3:
    string matriculaRemover;
    ....
    ....
    stand.removeCarro(matriculaRemover);//Remove o carro do stand
    break;
```